# Is safe and good design AllocateHWND to respond more than one thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, delphi-6

It's known that, in cases when one needs comunicate between UI thread and working thread, an hidden window must be created because of thread safety(handle reconstruction).

For exemplify:

- `Form1` has N dynamicaly created `TProgressBar` instances with the same name of a background running .
- Is always garanteed that `WM_REFRESH` will only be called inside Task Thread.
- `Form1` has `H : THandle property` that allocates the following procedure:

  procedure RefreshStat(var Message: TMessage); message WM_REFRESH;
- Inside `RefreshStat`, in cases when there is only 1 background thread I could easily use `L` and `W` parameter to map Task Id and position.

I don't know if the title says what I want to know, but let's imagine if we have an application that has multiple background tasks running.  
In my case I use `TProgressBar` to report progress the done.

Does `AllocateHwnd` garantee that all messages arrives with no race condition the hidden window? 
What happens if two or more tasks post the message at the same time?

If this needs to be controled manually, I wonder if there is something else to do besides creating another message loop system in the custom message.

I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Don't use THandle for a window. Use HWND. You use THandle for something that can be passed to CloseHandle, that is the Windows type HANDLE.

Comment: @Matheus, how do you want to update those progress bars from that hidden window ? In other words, how do you want to synchronize that hidden window with your form ? Wouldn't that be overcomplicated ? It might be enough for you to post directly [`progress bar messages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/windows/desktop/ff485990(v=vs.85).aspx) to the controls on your form.

Comment: @TLama The issue is window re-creation. The background tasks cannot use a VCL window handle since it can, and often does, get destroyed and re-creation. Hence the form needs a hidden window whose lifetime is deterministic.

Comment: @David, at progress bar creation/destruction, the form won't get re-created. Why would it happen ? And I can't see the reason why would I destroy such *monitoring* form by myself. The same applies for progress bars. Why would I destroy progress bar of a running task ? Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't see anything dangerous in posting messages directly to PBs.

Comment: @TLama We are not talking about destroying VCL objects, rather it is windows that get re-created. Many property changes lead to window re-creation.

Comment: @David, I know about that, and let it be. I'm not the one who needs to change window styles when the user should just watch progress bars (but maybe I imagined that progress dialog too much simple) :-)

Comment: @TLama External events like system theme change can lead to window re-creation. It's a real issue.

Comment: @David, ah, that's right! I forgot on such obvious window re-creators. Taking back my initial comment...

Comment: @All Well, I asked a question sometime ago and David suggest me to use this design because handle recreation, I never had any issue with that, but if it is a known bug it's always better to prevent

Comment: @Matheus, it's not a bug. It would be fine to post messages directly to progress bars, but there's a problem that when you change a Windows theme e.g., the form gets re-created to apply the new theme to itself and all the progress bars get new handles because of the form re-creation while you'd be storing the old, not valid ones in your worker threads.

Comment: @TLama You are right. But now I wonder, if I am in the new allocated hwnd context (inside custom message procedure scope) how can I access the "parent?" window controls and change its properties?

Comment: @Matheus, I would make an event for that *hidden window* object, make an instance of this object for a private field of your form and fire this event in a context of that form. Exactly like `TTimer` does. In code (without thread part) I would write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/r1SGjRxN) (not tested, I just know it compiles in Delphi 2009), but I'd say (and hope :-) it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message queue associated with a thread is a threadsafe queue. Both synchronous and asynchronous messages from multiple other thread are delivered safely no harmful date races. There is no need for any external synchronization when calling the Windows message API functions like SendMessage and PostMessage.

If two threads post or send messages to the same window at the same time, then there is no guarantee as to which message will be processed first. This is what is known as a benign race condition. If you want one message to be processed before the other then you must impose an ordering.

Comment: [+1] What intrigued me was that I thought that since AllocatHwnd creates a NEW window it SHOULD control the presented situation.

Comment: Since TLama touched on the subject, do you really think it is necessary to use AllocateHwnd for every situation like this?